# make a button behave like a submit button in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I try to make a confirm popup that going to jump when user click on a button of form.
If the user click on ok in the popup, the form goting to submit.
Its must to be dynamic becuse i have a lot of forms in one page and all form must to get the confirm popup.

I replaced the submit button with a normal button and when the user click on the button the confirm jumping.

```
<input type='button' name='submitButton' onclick="openPopup(this);">
```

Its work amazing but when the user into a text input and press on eneter its not submit the form.

What can i do?

Comment: use `type='submit'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('input').keypress(function(data) {
          if (data.keyCode == 13)
             data.target.form.submitButton.click();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following **JS**:

```
<input type='submit' name='submitButton' onclick="openPopup(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you accept confirmation then fire this event

```
 $('[name="submitButton"]').click();
```

Comment: if i use submit its submit the form. but i want to sbmit him when the confirm accept

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a `submit` button in your form you just need to handle this in the `keydown` event in your form `inputs` to check if <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed and click your button dynamically:

```
$("#formID").find('input[type=text]').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('[name="submitButton"]').click();
    }
});
```

**Note:**

I used `formID` as `id` of your form you just need to replace it with your form `id`.